# Procedure for SMS Notification in worklight

Tags: sms, ibm-mobilefirst

I am trying to implement sms notification using worklight. In worklight i have imported the example given from the ibm site. I also have download the sms gateway ultimate in the mobile phone and created a service.NOw I downloaded the .apk into my mobile and installed the app 
in my mobile phone.I subscribed with my own number . And i invoked the adapter in the worklight studio to send the notification. But i am getting  error that states **file not found** in the sms gateway in my mobile. I am searching for a solution .Can you guys help me

Comment: Can you tell where is this error seen ? Also, when do you get this error ? If the error is coming from the gateway app that you used, then you should probably consult the gateway app's author to find out what it means and when the error occurs.

Comment: Can you give me a good site for sms notification in worklight

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I completed the implementation. First imported the worklight sms notification sample for worklight 6 from ibm site. Then in my android mobile, I downloaded the SMS gateway ultimate. Then i installed it in my mobile. I installed the worklight app in my mobile too. Then i created a service in my mobile with sms gateway ultimate with name - balaji sms gateway port -52139 and connected too wifi.I checked the ipaddress with the info in the top right cornor it was 117.96.25.154.

```
And in the smsConfig.xml file i gave editted like the following



  <gateway id="myGateway" hostname="117.96.25.154" port="52139" 
                programName="/send.html" toParamName="smsto" textParamName="smsbody">

            <parameter encode="false" name="smstype" value="sms"/>
            <parameter encode="false" name="Username" value="balaji"/>
            <parameter encode="false" name="Password" value="sabdhar"/>
        </gateway>
```

Comment: On running the app according to your procedure, the logcat shows the error- `"client init failed. The connection to service is unavailable"` Can you please help me with this?